# Yehoshua bin Nun & Calev ben Yefuneh, and their order in parshat Shelach

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-shelach

In parshat Shelach, the Torah records both Yehoshua bin Nun and Calev ben Yefuneh not consistenly in the same order when both mentioned in the same verse.

For example:

- Bamidbar 14:6, Yehoshua comes first וִֽיהוֹשֻׁ֣עַ בִּן־נ֗וּן וְכָלֵב֙ בֶּן־יְפֻנֶּ֔ה מִן־הַתָּרִ֖ים אֶת־הָאָ֑רֶץ קָֽרְע֖וּ בִּגְדֵיהֶֽם
- Bamidbar 14:30, Calev comes first אִם־אַתֶּם֙ תָּבֹ֣אוּ אֶל־הָאָ֔רֶץ אֲשֶׁ֤ר נָשָׂ֨אתִי֙ אֶת־יָדִ֔י לְשַׁכֵּ֥ן אֶתְכֶ֖ם בָּ֑הּ כִּ֚י אִם־כָּלֵ֣ב בֶּן־יְפֻנֶּ֔ה וִֽיהוֹשֻׁ֖עַ בִּן־נֽוּן
- Bamidbar 14:38, Yehoshua comes first וִֽיהוֹשֻׁ֣עַ בִּן־נ֔וּן וְכָלֵ֖ב בֶּן־יְפֻנֶּ֑ה חָיוּ֙ מִן־הָֽאֲנָשִׁ֣ים הָהֵ֔ם הַהֹֽלְכִ֖ים לָת֥וּר אֶת־הָאָֽרֶץ

Is there any significance for being mentioned in the Torah in different order?

Gut Shabbos

Answer (score 2):

The [Ibn Ezra](https://www.sefaria.org/Ibn_Ezra_on_Numbers.14.29.1?lang=he) on these pesukim seems to be bothered by this question. He explains that the pesukim in which Moshe is speaking, he puts Yehoshua first in light of his higher level. However when Hashem is speaking in regards to this incident, He mentions Kalev first in light of the fact that he was the one who got everyone to be quiet and listen to how great the land was.

> ויהושע בן נון. הזכירו משה בתחלה לגודל מעלתו

> כי אם כלב. הקדים כלב כי הוא הקדים ויהס

> ויהושע בן נון. דברי משה קודם כלב